# SSH private key permissions suddenly changed

Tags: release-loki, updates, permissions, ssh

Suddenly I get the "unprotected private key file" warning when trying to ssh.  There is a server I connect to every few days and have never had this issue before, suggesting that somehow the permissions on my id_rsa file changed since the last time I used ssh.

I install the AppCenter updates frequently and wonder whether one of these updates could have been responsible?  Has anyone else experienced this?  Else I may have been hacked somehow...

Answer (score 1):

The warning is about the permissions of your private ssh key on your local host (`~/.ssh/id_rsa`) and you might want to try to reset the permissions to their defaults with

```
chmod 700 ~/.ssh/
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Comment: Yes, I did that, but my question was why the permissions on id_rsa changed.  I am pretty sure id_rsa was at 600 when I last successfully ssh'd and somehow it changed to 644 since then.  The directory .ssh/ probably was not at 700 but it is now so thank you for that.  Still wondering whether I got compromised or whether a system update caused the permissions change.

Comment: System updates do not write anything in your home directory normally.